# XMLHttpRequest works in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to write an function that collects information from a contact form, makes a XMLHttpRequest to postmail.invotes.com/send, which forwards an email. The weird thing is, this code works in Firefox but it doesn't work in Chrome.

In the Network tab, the send request is **(failed)** with **net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID** ; is that something I can fix, or the postmail.invotes.com website needs to fix?

```
function js_send() {  // User has clicked send email button.
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            js_onSuccess();  //Return sent message alert.
        } else
        if(request.readyState == 4) {
            js_onError(request.response);  //Return failed message alert.
        }
    };

    let fname = document.querySelector("#" + form_id_js + " [name='fname']").value;
    let reply_to = document.querySelector("#" + form_id_js + " [name='reply_to']").value;
    let subject = document.querySelector("#" + form_id_js + " [name='subject']").value;
    let text = document.querySelector("#" + form_id_js + " [name='text']").value;

    if (fname && reply_to && subject && text) {  // Only try to send a message if user has entered all 4 values.
        data_js['subject'] = `You have a new message from your Portfolio: ${subject}`;
        data_js['text'] = `You have a new message from your Portfolio! \n\n Subject: ${subject} \n Email: ${reply_to} \n Text: ${text} \n Sender: ${fname}`;
        let params = toParams(data_js);

        request.open("POST", "https://postmail.invotes.com/send", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        request.send(params);
    } else {  // User has not entered all 4 values.
        alertMessage.innerHTML = "Please fill out form completely.";
    }
}
```

Comment: https://comodosslstore.com/resources/how-to-fix-net-err_cert_date_invalid-error-on-google-chrome/ If your OS's clock is right, it's probably an issue on their end

Comment: I would swap out `request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {` with `request.onload = function(){`. Just a comment.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Yes, it's set to EST. I also tried on Safari on my phone with no success.

Comment: @StackSlave: I tried swapping out the first line request.onreadystatechange = function() { with your code request.onload = function() { . In this case the Firefox still works, and Chrome just hangs there, & never returns either js_onSuccess() or js_onError().